# Smooth lifting criteria of smooth vector fields given smooth surjective submersion whose fibers are connected.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I am working on an exercise:

Suppose $F : M \to N$ is a smooth submersion, where $M$ and $N$ are positive-dimensional smooth manifolds. Given $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ and $Y \in \mathfrak{X}(N)$, we say that $X$ is a lift of $Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are $F$-related. A vector field $V \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is said to be vertical if $V$ is everywhere tangent to the fibers of $F$ (or, equivalently, if $V$ is $F$-related to the zero vector field on $N$).

Assume in addition that $F$ is surjective with connected fibers. Show thata vector field $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is a lift of a smooth vector field on $N$ if and only if $[V, X]$ is vertical whenever $V \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is vertical.

I have previously shown one direction, and also have shown that if $F$ is surjective, $X$ is a lift of some smooth vector field on $N$ if and only if $d F_p(X_p) = d F_q(X_q)$ if $p, q$ are in the same fiber.

To show that $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is a lift of a smooth vector field on $N$ if $[V, X]$ is vertical whenever $V \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is vertical, I considered below approach.

Since each fiber is connected by the assumption, I thought maybe I can show $\{ q \in F^{-1}(F(p)) :  d F_p(X_p) = d F_q(X_q)\}$ is both open and closed, and conclude that $\{ q \in F^{-1}(F(p)) :  d F_p(X_p) = d F_q(X_q)\}$ is $F^{-1}(F(p))$ for each $p \in M$, but I am not sure how  to show that $\{ q \in F^{-1}(F(p)) :  d F_p(X_p) = d F_q(X_q)\}$ is open.

Answer (score 3):

For one direction, since $X$  is a lift of smooth vector field on $N$,there exist a vector field on $N$ ,$F$-related to $X$, so by natruality of Lie braket $$dF([V,X]) = [dF(V),dF(X)] = [0,dF(X)] = 0$$

For the other direction ,the point is to show that the value $dF(X)$ is locally constant on the fiber as you have noticed.Intuitively inside the small neiborhood center at $p$ of the firber,there exist a ray connected any point $p \to q$ inside the neiborhood.the vector field $V$ corresponding to this integral curve in the fiber is verticle.So we know $[V,X] $ is verticle.

Using the definition of Lie derivative we know $$[V,X] = \frac{d}{dt}(d\theta_{-t})X$$ is verticle ,where $V$ is the vector field correspond to the flow on the fiber.

i.e. $dF(\frac{d}{dt}(d\theta_{-t})X) = 0$,what we want to show is that $$\frac{d}{dt}dF(X) = 0$$ along the integral curve.

To do this $$dF(\lim_t \frac{X_{\theta_t(p)} - (d\theta_t)_p(X)}{t}) = \lim_t(\frac{dF(X_{\theta_t(p)}) - dF\circ d\theta (X_p)}{t}) =0$$

Observe that $F\circ \theta = F$ since the flow is along the verticle direction,so ,we know
$$\lim_t \frac{dF_{\theta_t(p)(X)} - dF(X_p) }{t} = 0$$

that's exactly the locally constant of $dF(X)$!

Comment: Why is $F \circ \theta = F$ since the flow is along the vertical direction?

Comment: since $F$ will collapse the fiber into a single point, the flow line on the fiber will map to the same point , $\theta$ is a flow that image contains in a single fiber@nomadicmathematician

Comment: Oh right thank you. Could you help me understand why $V$ is everywhere tangent to the fibers of $F$ is equivalent to $V$ is $F$-related to the zero vector field on $N$? I'm having trouble understanding the definition of vertical vector fields.

Comment: So you construct $V$ to be the infinitesimal generator of the ray connecting the two points $p,q$ in a fiber of $F$. Could you help me see why this vector field would be vertical by the definition given here? It's intuitively clear but I cannot write it down.

Comment: Since $F$ is submersion ,$F$ has local coordinate representation $F(x_1,..,x_n) = (x_1,...,x_r)$ so we can see the vertial vector fields which spans by $\partial x_{r+1},...,\partial x_{n}$ is F related zero vector fields on $N$

Comment: Yes but how does that show that the vector field constructed from the ray is vertical?

Comment: Since the fiber is embedded submanifold (since $F$ has constant rank) we can just take the slice chart for $F^{-1}(p)$  in slice chart we can connect them by the ray and the ray is vertical since the coordinate of the ray has constant $(x_1,...,x_r)$ , so the vector field is spanned by $\partial x_{r+1},...,\partial x_{n}
$ @nomadicmathematician

Comment: Okay so if we take such a slice chart then $p$ and $q$ have $0$ on $x_{r+1},\dots, x_n$, and we can connect them by a ray that stays on $x_{r+1}=\cdots = x_n=0$. But then isn't this integral curve spanned by $\partial x_1 , \dots, \partial x_r$ with zero coordinates for $\partial x_{r+1},\dots \partial x_n$?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician ,the first $r$ coordinate on the fiber are the same the last $n-r$ can differ

Comment: Sorry I was confusing things. One last thing. For the limit inside $dF$, shouldn't it be $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{d(\theta_{-t})_{\theta_t(p)}(X_{\theta_t(p)})-X_p}{t}$?This is what $\frac{d}{dt}(d\theta_{-t})X$ seems to mean and what I have in my text. Curious how you got the formula above.

Comment: they are the same just two side limit of the same thing, you can also prove it using $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{d(\theta_{-t})_{\theta_t(p)}(X_{\theta_t(p)})-X_p}{t}
$

Comment: Can we have a proof without using Lie derivatives? In the book since this exercise is before the introduction of Lie derivatives, we should try not to use them.

Comment: I am not sure yet

Comment: Not that if $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, push forward $dF$ can *not* automatically ensure $dF(X) \in \mathfrak{X}(N)$. I don't think it is a valid proof.

Comment: Sorry Yan Zhu I almost have forgetten how I proved this result,  I will check it later

Answer (score 2):

Probably, this is too late but I would like to know if my proof has a mistake.

First, let $S_c$ denote a fiber s.t. $c\in N$ and $S_c=F^{-1}(c)$, thus $F$ smooth submersion implies $S_c$ is a properly embedded submanifold of $M$, whose codimension is equal to the dimension of $N$($\text{dim }N=n$). In addition, there exist $(V,(y^1,y^{2},\cdots,y^{n})=\psi)$ a chart about $c$, this chart allows us to define $b^{s}:F^{-1}(V)\to\mathbb{R}$ from the following equation,
$$dF_r(X_r)=\sum_{s=1}^{n}b^{s}(r)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{s}}\right\vert_{F(r)}$$
, i.e. $b^{s}(r)=X_r(y^s\circ F)$. Our goal is to prove $b^s(r)$ is constant on $S_c$.

Therefore, if $[W,X]=0$ as $W$ is a vertical vector field.

$$[W,X](y^{s}\circ F)=0\Rightarrow W_r(X(y^{s}\circ F))=X_r\left(W(y^{s}\circ F)\right)=0$$
Here, $X(y^{s}\circ F):F^{-1}(V)\to\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow X_r(y^{s}\circ F)=dF_r(X_r)y^{s}=b^s(r)$, then $W_r b^{s}=0$ as $r\in F^{-1}(V)$.

Let $p\in S_c$ and let's define $H_c=\left\lbrace q\in S_c, dF_p(X_p)=dF_q(X_q)\right\rbrace$, by definition $p\in H_c$.

Claim: $H_c$ is open in $S_c$, analogously $S_c-H_c$ is open in $S_c$.

Let's suppose $q\in H_c$ then there exists $(U,(x^1,x^2,\cdots,x^m)=\varphi)$ a slice chart about $q$ s.t. $U\cap S_c=\left\lbrace q\in U,  x^{k+1}(q)=x^{k+2}(q)=\cdots=x^m(q)=0\right\rbrace$ , $U\subseteq F^{-1}(V)$ and $\varphi(U)$ is a ball, thus if $r\in U\cap S_c\rightarrow W_r\in\text{span}\left\lbrace \partial^x_1\vert_r,\cdots,\partial^x_k\vert_r\right\rbrace$

\begin{align*}
W_r b^s=0&\Rightarrow 0=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right\vert_r b^s\\
\text{If, }\hat{b}^s(a^1,a^2,\cdots,a^m)&=b^s\circ\varphi^{-1}(a^1,a^2,\cdots,a^m)\\
\hat{b}^s(a^1,a^2,\cdots,a^m)&=\hat{b}^s(a^{k+1},a^{k+2},\cdots,a^m)
\end{align*}
Conclusion, $b^s$ is constant on $U\cap S_c$ for all $c\in V$ then $dF_r(X_r)=dF_q(X_q)=dF_p(X_p)$ for all $r\in U\cap S_c$, thus $H_c$ is open in $S_c$. On the other hand, if $q\not\in H_c$ then $dF_r(X_r)=dF_q(X_q)\not=dF_p(X_p)$ for all $r\in U\cap S_c$, i.e. $H_c$. complement is open in $S_c$.

Then, the connectedness of the fibers implies $dF_p(X_p)=dF_q(X_q)$ as $F(p)=F(q)$ and you probably know this is a sufficient condition to assure the existence of $Y$ smooth vector field on $N$, $Y_{F(p)}=dF_p(X_p)$, in fact this the unique vector field which is F-related to $X$.

Comment: Why is $[W,X]=0$? Vertical means $dF[W,X]=0$ on $S_c$. And I don't get why you have $W_r(X(y^s \circ F))$ and $X_r(W(y^s\circ F))=0$. Also $W_r b^s=0$ does not guarantee $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_r b^s=0$, the coefficient functions of $W_r$ could be zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is problem 8-18(d) in John Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. As mentioned one direction is easy, we focus on the other direction. Assume that whenever $ V\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is vertical, $[V, X]$ is vertical.

To show $X$ is a lift, it is sufficient to show that $dF_p(X_p) = dF_q(X_q)$ whenever $F(q) = F(p)$ by Problem 8-18(c) in the book. (Part (c) can be easily proved by Thm 4.30 in the book)

Because $F$ is a surjective submersion, $F^{-1}(c)$ is an embedded submanifold in $M$ (denoted as S and assume its dimension is $r$) $\forall c \in N$. Suppose we can show that $\forall$ $p \in S$, it has a open neighborhood $U_p$ in $M$ such that $dF_{q}(X_q)$ is constant $\forall$ $q \in U_p \cap S$. Then by the connectedness assumption, we can connect any point in $S$ with $p$ by a path. Due to the compactness of the path, we can argue $dF_q (X_q)$ is constant $\forall$ $q \in S$.

Note that $V$ is vertical implies $V|_{S} \in \mathfrak{X}(S)$, since $F$ is $S$'s a defining map (see proposition 5.38). By rank theorem, $\forall p \in S$, there exists a $r$-slice chart $U_p$ for $S$ such that $\forall x \in U_p$

$$
F(x^1, x^2, \dots, x^r, x^{r+1}, \dots, x^m) = (x^{r+1}, \dots, x^{m})
$$
Let $V$ be any vertical vector field on M. Then in chart $U_p$, we have
$V = V^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ with $V^j = 0$ for $j > r$. Within same chart, we have
$$
[V, X] = (VX^j - XV^j)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}.
$$
By hypothesis, $[V, X] \in \mathfrak{X}(S)$, we conclude that $VX^j = 0$ for $j > r$. Thus, $X^j$ only depends on $(x^{r+1}, \dots, x^m)$.
Locally, $\forall q \in S \cap U_p$, we have
$$
dF(X)|_q = dF(X^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})|_q = \sum_{k > r} X^k \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\right|_c
$$
Because the LHS of the above equation only depends on $c$, $dF(X)|_q$ is a constant.

Comment: Why does $X^j$ only depend on $(x^{r+1},\dots, x^m)$ because $VX^j=0$ for $j>r$? And why is $dF_q(X_q)$ constant for all $q\in U_p \cap S$ because $(x^{r+1},\dots, x^m)$ is a single point on $S$?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician For your first question, since V is any vector vector field. We can choose $V = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ where $i \leq r$. Then  $\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x^i} = 0$. It implies that $X^j$ is independent of $x^i$.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician I clarify your second question by ending the last step of the proof. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean that $V$ is any vector field. Why does $V$ being a vertical vector field allow you to just choose it to be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ for $i \le r$?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician We can choose $V$ to be any vertical field. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ $i \leq r$ is a vertical field.